# BlockFrost API Historical Supply By Epoch Data?

Tags: staking, supply

Currently https://cardano-mainnet.blockfrost.io/api/v0/network gets the current network supply data. Does anyone know an endpoint from any API that has historical supply usage data by epoch?

Comment: Bumping question - I'm also interested to know if this is possible via API calls.